# Google search console added my 21 URls in poor section of core web vitals and showing it as 126 URLs

Tags: next.js, canonical-link, google-search-console, core-web-vitals

I recently fixed my CLS and LCP issues and hoped that all my URLs will be fixed. I am using next.js at the front end and my issues were not fixed at all. My current CLS of each page is 0.039 and LCP is 2.5 for mobile which is ok as per google guidelines.
But most importantly, I am very confused why the hell google counting 26 URLs,s ad 126. The below screenshot will explain all what i am facing
[image: This is the screenshot of google search console failed URLs]

As you can see it is showing 126 URLS but at the right-hand side, there total of 20 URLs.I also want to clarify that I am using the canonical link tag in the head section of each slug page like this

```
    <link rel="canonical" href={`https://${DOMAIN}/jobs/${query.slug}`} />
```

in the slug page.I explained everything what problem i am facing right now .So please answer if you know anything about it,

Comment: As you can see from the sidebar it says "up to 20", meaning it'll only show up to 20 even if there's more than that.

Comment: Ok,that means there is no canonical issue.

Comment: Why the poor url increasing even if i fixed them.i started new validation day before yesterday.In status it shows 220 pending and 0 failed.should i hope that these will be fixed because lcp and cls issue got fixed on every page as i checked these 20 urls on page speed tool of google